# Handle FTP error in shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to do an ftp from a shell script, called by another one(parent script). the code  is something like this:

```
ftp -inv <<EOF
open $hostname
user $username $password

binary


cd $dir
put $renamed_file

bye

EOF
```

when I check for the return code like:

```
exitStatus=$?
```

it always returns 0, even if the ftp fails. I am new to shell scripting and is struggling with how to resolve this. Can someone please help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: I agree with @CharlesDalsass but if you're really lucky you might find an ftp client that exits with a non-zero code on error. Having `bye` in you command list is almost certain to overrule that behavior, so try taking that out. Else, I used to run a `dir` command to see if the file I was expecting had arrived. If the name doesn't change, then you have to del or rename your existing copy before starting the `ftp`. Also, I think there are quite a few questions here on S.O. for this issue, so read thru, you may find better techniques. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to get back the response you want if you look at the bash (or whatever shell) exit status. Bash thinks the command is working just fine - even if it's really an error. Your best bet is to use "batch mode" (your FTP program should have something like that). Capture any error output to a file or STDERR and parse to find your errors.